# Effect on the spectral radius of a Hermitian matrix by the addition of a rank 2 Hermitian matrix

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, eigenvalues-eigenvectors

Let $A$ and $B$ be two Hermitian matrices of order $n$ such that $\mbox{rank}(B)=2$. Then how is the spectral radius of $A$, denoted by $\rho(A)$, related to that of $A+B$?

That is -  Is there any relationship exist between $\rho(A)$ and $\rho(A+B)$?

Answer (score 1):

For Hermitian matrices, we have $\rho(A+B) \leq \rho(A) + \rho(B)$.  In general, we have $\|A+B\|\leq \|A\| + \|B\|$ where $\|\cdot\|$ denotes the spectral norm.  When $A$ is Hermitian, $\|A\| = \rho(A)$.

If you want to incorporate the rank of $B$, then there is more we could say about the particular eigenvalues using [Weyl's inequalities](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Weyl's_inequality#Weyl.27s_inequality_in_matrix_theory).